# Why I have issue with the svn cleanup?

Tags: svn

Help me, please, with an issue:

```
build@subversion:~> find /home/build/cruise-work/cruise-checkout/30.0/ | grep rep-cache.db
build@subversion:~> cd /home/build/cruise-work/cruise-checkout/30.0/
build@subversion:~/cruise-work/cruise-checkout/30.0> svn cleanup
svn: E200031: sqlite[S8]: attempt to write a readonly database
svn: E200031: Additional errors:
svn: E200031: sqlite[S8]: attempt to write a readonly database
build@subversion:~/cruise-work/cruise-checkout/30.0>
```

EDIT1:

> build@subversion:~/cruise-work/cruise-checkout/30.0> chmod g+w
>   rep-cache.db
>       chmod: cannot access `rep-cache.db': No such file or directory

EDIT2:

I haven't the rep-cache.db file at all:

```
> sudo find / | grep rep-cache.db root's password:
> /usr/src/subversion-1.8.11/subversion/libsvn_fs_fs/rep-cache-db.sql
> /usr/src/subversion-1.8.11/subversion/libsvn_fs_fs/rep-cache-db.h
```

Comment: Why is my question getting minuses? What wrong with it?

Comment: I got the same error message. In my case the file system with the working copy was mounted read-only.

Comment: I received this error when I tried to run `svn cleanup` without root permissions.

Answer (score 2):

this is caused by wrong permissions on a file on the SVN server.

The file “rep-cache.db” will most likely have wrong permissions like the group not having write access to the file.

A simple chmod g+w on the file will be enough for the error message not appearing again.

Comment: I haven't such file at all. I give example above.

Comment: Test `chmod g+w rep-cache.db` and paste the result here

Comment: I added the result in question.

Comment: find `db` folder. `rep-cache.db` is in `db\rep-cache.db`. First change the path, then use `chmode...`

Comment: I have the same problem during running cruise control across web interface.

Comment: I haven't such file. I edited my question. Anyone can help me?

Comment: This error mostly raised when there's no permission for a file. You should recheck all permissions from administrator. The command I told you about give the write permission to all in a group

Comment: I had the same issue `sudo svn cleanup` end then `sudo svn merge ^/trunk  branches/branch` solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Things seemed to get in a mess for me after I have been recursively changing permissions on directories and had given ownership to another user. I am assuming that the .svn directories now belonged to that other user and I did not have permission to alter them. Using `sudo`, just for the cleanup, solved the problem.

`sudo svn cleanup`

Answer (score 0):

Often this issues happens because you are not running svn commands as super user. So just add sudo to the commands and try that.

Comment: A bit dangerous. IMHO it could be more advisable to just sudo to the user owning the .svn files (i.e. jenkins, subversion, etc.)